# Is it possible to get VAT Refund with the D-Type Visa when leaving Slovenia?

Tags: visas, taxes, tax-refunds, slovenia

I am currently an Erasmus internship student in Slovenia. I am planning to use tax free here. My visa is D-Type (103 days, MLT). I am leaving after 1 month. Is it possible ?

Comment: When you leave after one month, where will you be going?

Comment: @phoog Turkey. I am a non-EU citizen.

Comment: Note that if its even possible for non-visitor entrants (not sure that it is), it will only apply to items you are taking out of the EU Customs area.

Comment: Are you leaving to visit home or are you leaving permanently?

Comment: @Peter Green I am leaving permanently because my erasmus season is end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VAT is handled by [Financial Administration of the Republic of Slovenia](http://www.fu.gov.si/en/taxes_and_other_duties/areas_of_work/value_added_tax_vat/).

You can find an [Identification and obligations of foreign tax payers](http://www.fu.gov.si/fileadmin/Internet/Davki_in_druge_dajatve/Podrocja/Davek_na_dodano_vrednost/Opis/GB_Podrobnejsi_opis_1_izdaja_Identification_and_obligations_of_foreign_tax_payers.pdf) document on their site, where the rules are stated in English. I believe you might fall under the `VAT refund to passengers without place of residence in The Union` category (Section 9.), IANAL, however.

It says here that when buying, you need to inform the seller of your intent, upon which they should provide you with a form (DDV-VP, `DDV` is an alias for `VAT`), which you both fill out and you then take to customs. Only after you get approval at a customs office (get stamps and such), you return to the seller or an approved partner to get the refund.

Here's the relevant part of the linked document:

> 9.1 Conditions for VAT refund
>
> A taxable person established in a third country (subject to the conditions laid
>       down in ZDDV-1), shall be entitled to a  refund of VAT charged for goods
>       or services supplied to him by other taxable persons within the territory of Slovenia,  or charged on the importation of goods into 
>       Slovenia. The passenger without the seat on the territory of Slovenia or
>       another person for his/her account, which sends or transports exempt supplies 
>       of goods from Slovenia outside the Union in the personal luggage, is entitled to
>       VAT refund.
>
> The passenger without place of residence in the Union is a passenger, 
>       whose permanent or usual residence is not in the Union . “Permanent or usual 
>       residence” is a place, which is stated in the passport,  identity card or another identification document,  recognised as a  valid one by 
>       Slovenia.
>
> The right to VAT refund refers to goods, bought in Slovenia, including 
>       replacement parts, which are due to repairs or servicing incorporated into motor
>       vehicles, vessels or aircrafts, registered outside the tax territory of the 
>       Union, and not to mineral oils, alcohol, alcoholic beverages and tobacco 
>       products.
>
> The following conditions shall be fulfilled at VAT refund:
>
> - that the value of goods bought with included VAT on one 
>     invoice,  issued to the same buyer at the same seller, exceeds 50
>     EUR;
> - that the seller has fulfilled and issued DDV-VP form or other document,  the subject matter of which corresponds to DDV-VP form, for the goods sold; the original invoice or invoices from the previous indent shall be enclosed with the form;
> - that the buyer took the goods outside the Union before expiry of 
>         the third month, which follows the month of purchase;  sending goods
>         via mail or via other appropriate way under condition that goods bought
>         leave the customs territory of the Union is also considered as removal of 
>         goods;
> - that the border customs authority has been given access to goods purchased
>         and after the examination it verifies the original DDV-VP form and originals
>         of invoices enclosed and it enters the date of removal of goods from the 
>         Union.
>
> If these conditions are fulfilled,  the customs authority with the 
>       signature and stamp verifies originals of invoices and DDV-VP form and it
>       enters the date of removal of goods from the customs territory of the 
>       Union into DDV-VP form. It returns originals of invoices and DDV-VP form 
>       to the buyer and keeps one copy of the form for needs of subsequent
>       supervision over removal of goods from the Union.
>
> 9.2 VAT refund method
>
> The seller shall refund paid VAT to the buyer if within six months from the day 
>       of issuing DDV-VP form he/she submits the original DDV-VP form, which is 
>       verified by the customs authority, together with verified originals of invoices,
>       to the seller or another person, who is authorised by the seller for tax refund.
>       The verified original of DDV-VP form and verified originals of invoices 
>       represent VAT refund claim.
>
> The buyer may submit VAT refund claim in person, via another legal entity or
>       individual or via mail. If the buyer submits the claim via mail, he/she shall 
>       state also the invoice number, to which the paid VAT shall be refunded.
>
> If the buyer fulfils conditions for VAT refund, the seller pays the amount to 
>       him/her in cash or the amount is paid to the account, stated by the buyer in the
>       claim, within 15 days after the day of receipt of the claim.